# htaccess: remove port from HTTP_HOST

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need a `%{HTTP_HOST}` environment variable without the port.

I have a dev server under 8080 port and prod server under 80.

This rule fail on dev because `%{HTTP_HOST}` on dev server is eg.: myhost.com:8080

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/cache/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
```

there is a way for make HTTP_HOST without the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can simply parse the actual host from the combination of host and port:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^:]+)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%1/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/cache/%{1}/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html" [L]
```